# Codenameone - list component run slowly on real-phone

Tags: codenameone

Im a newbie codenameone.

I have a "Customer List - FORM". It has a List(com.​codename1.​ui.​List) with setRenderer my model(Customer):

public class CustRow extends Container implements ListCellRenderer {

```
private Label lblfocus = new Label("");
private Label lblname = new Label("");
private Label lblphone = new Label("");
private GuLabel lblnotes = new GuLabel("");

public CustRow() {
    this.setUIID("LISTITEM");
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Container mcselect = new Container(new FlowLayout());
    CheckBox chkselect = new CheckBox();
    chkselect.setUIID("LABEL");
    mcselect.addComponent(chkselect);
    this.addComponent(mcselect);

    Container leftcol = new Container(new BorderLayout());

    leftcol.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, lblname);

    leftcol.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, lblphone);

    this.addComponent(leftcol);
    lblname.setUIID("LABEL");
    lblphone.setUIID("LABEL");
    lblnotes.setUIID("LBLNOTES");
    this.addComponent(lblnotes);

}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Customer value, int index, boolean isSelected) {

    lblname.setText(value.getName());
    lblphone.setText(value.getPhone());
    lblnotes.setText(value.getNotes());
    return this;
}

public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
    return lblfocus;
}
```

}

I have 2 problem following:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuOhD.jpg - 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8GpP.jpg 
1. When I ran app on myPhone (android 4.2), next to scroll to choose item, it Slowly.
2. When I make one checkbox on ListItem checked, All checkbox is checked.

Help me! Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is difficult I suggest avoiding the renderer paradigm if you are a beginner to Codename One and just using the `GenericListCellRenderer` instead or better yet just using `MultiList`.

Both effectively solve the issue of working with checkboxes & perform well.

I would guess your model is causing some of the performance issues you are seeing.